# Volley request too slow

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

My app crashes because the images ArrayList is empty when I set the adapter, I figured that out by putting a toast message right after I parse my JSON request, and a Toast message after I initialize my adapter, "second" gets printed first on screen and the app crashes right after, does it have to do with my internet? Or am I missing something, here's my code, thanks!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    mRequestQueue = mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue();

    //First Toast message inside this method 
    sendAPIRequest();

    //after you get the images
    mCustomSwipeAdapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this, images);

    //SECOND TOAST
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Second", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomSwipeAdapter);

    mCustomSwipeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void sendAPIRequest(){
    String requestURL = "";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestURL, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            parseJSONResponse(response);

            //FIRST TOAST : SHOULD BE CALLED FIRST
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

public void parseJSONResponse(JSONObject response) {
    if (response != null || response.length() != 0) {
        try {
            JSONObject GObject = response.getJSONObject("game");
            String name = "N/A";
            if (GObject.has("name") && !GObject.isNull("name")) { name = GObject.getString("name"); }

            if (GObject.has("screenshots") && !GObject.isNull("screenshots")) {
                JSONArray screenShotsArray = GObject.getJSONArray("screenshots");
                for (int i = 0; i < screenShotsArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject screenshot = screenShotsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String screenshotURL = screenshot.getString("url");

                    images.add(screenshotURL);
                }
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it have to do with my internet? Or am I missing something ...

Both.  It happens because you have a race condition.

From what I can make out, your `images` list is being populated asynchronously by the `onResponse` callback.  Basically, that happens when your app gets the responses to the API requests that it is making.  That is going to take *at least* milliseconds, and possibly seconds (or longer).

But your app is (so you say) crashing soon after the swipe adapter is registered, and the evidence is that the `images` list has not been populated.

There are three possibilities:

- There is something wrong with the requests you are sending which is causing the API requests to not give you any response.  (Hypothetically, you could have authentication wrong or something.)
- The API requests are taking a long time because of internet connection speed, congestion, or the remote server being slow.
- The API requests are taking a short time ... but the adapter registration is even quicker.

If (hypothetically) there is a problem with your requests you will need to fix that.  But both of the other scenarios have to be fixed by:

- modifying the code that uses the images to work properly if there are no images (yet), or
- modifying the code to wait until the image loading has completed before registering the adapter.

Comment: Thanks, turns out my internet is all right,  I set the adapter to my ViewPager after I successfully loaded and was 100% sure the onResponse returns what I wanted, in this case JSON. So the code where I set my adapter and notify the data was changed; I moved it right after I finish parsing so in my parseJSONResponse, method, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code in your onResponse callback :

```
//after you get the images
mCustomSwipeAdapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this, images);

//SECOND TOAST
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Second", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomSwipeAdapter);

mCustomSwipeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Volley adds your requests in queue , so better do all the dependent tasks in Response or Error callback only.